Problem with batch processing using Points to path
I am having issues trying to use Points to Path (batch processing).
I got stuck every time I try to select multiple layers in a folder and I need to restart QGIS.
QGIS version installed on my laptop: 3.28
Any suggestion?
Thanks

you may try to update QGIS, current version is 3.36.1: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html
